# Select next popup with Magnific Popup (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm using the Magnific Popup library. I need to have the next nearest popup-div-content load when the link is clicked. It works for hard coded id's but I need it to work generically (next) because this is going into a cms and I will not know how many items are being loaded.

```
<a href="#" class="open-popup-link">1st link</a>
<div class="white-popup mfp-hide">
    <p>First popup content</p>
</div><br>

<a href="#" class="open-popup-link">2nd link</a>
<div class="white-popup mfp-hide">
    <p>Second popup content</p>
</div><br>

<a href="#" class="open-popup-link">3nd link</a>
<div class="white-popup mfp-hide">
    <p>Third popup content</p>
</div>

$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    items: {
        // src: $('.white-popup'), // works but loads all
        src: $(this).next('.white-popup'), // should load only next popup div
        type: 'inline'
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryAcid/XadjS/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're passing in your object literal  in to the .magnificPopup() function, you're not inside a function. In other words, you're still in the global scope. So `this` is still referring to the window, and not the div, which is what you seem to be expecting here.

In order to reference the DOM node with `this`, you can instead bind the popup within JQuery's `.each()` like so:

```
$('.open-popup-link').each(function(){
    $(this).magnificPopup({
      items: {
      src: $(this).next('.white-popup'), // should load the next popup
      type: 'inline'
      }
    })
});
```

You can see a working example at

http://jsfiddle.net/XadjS/4/